# Select non-parentheses and non-quotes comma

Tags: php, regex

When i use preg_split with

```
/['\"][^'\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\,[^'\"\\\\]*)*['\"](*SKIP)(?!)|\,/
```

for

```
max(min(2, 3, 5, 19, 5), 2)
```

its splits like

```
    [0] => min(2
    [1] =>  3
    [2] =>  5
    [3] =>  19
    [4] =>  5)
    [5] =>  2
```

I want to select non-parentheses and non-quotes comma.
So:

```
[0] => min(2, 3, 5, 19, 5)
[1] => 2
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but in the general case you might want to implement a rudimentary parser, which can dissect any number of nested function calls.  That is, regex may not be the best tool for this job.

Comment: It is a very unclear question and as such, even [`\w+\([^()]+\)|\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/TyHIj7/1) will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed about using a non-regex method for this, as this can get unwieldy fast. But if you're curious, read on.

Technically, the comma you wish to find *is* in a group of parentheses, enclosed in `max()`. If you only ever want to look inside a single top-level function, you can use something such as this:

```
(?:^max\\(|(([\'\"])(?:\\\\.|(?!\\g{-1}).)*+\\g{-1})|\\((\\\\.|(?1)|[^()\'\"]|\\((?-1)*+\\))*+\\))(*SKIP)(?!)|,
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/O7kFRc/1

If there can be other top-level functions, such as `max(a, b) + min(c, d)`, then other methods must be used. But there's no need to open that can of worms just yet.